# Closing/killing "Android Terminal Emulator" app

Tags: terminal

I have a Sprint LG G3 running Android 4.4.2. I'm using [Android Terminal Emulator](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki) by Jackpal. It respawns after I close the app. I see the terminal process and the child shell but killing that way seems too manual.

When I closed the only window from the dropdown list at the top, it closes temporarily, then reappears in the "Recent apps" list. There is an un-swipeable notification that says "Terminal session is running". When I tap on either the thumbnail or notification, the "Window 1" comes back.

The only workaround I've found is rebooting.

Any better ideas to really close this app?

Comment: Did you try `am force-stop jackpal.androidterm` or [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en) to kill it?

Comment: Open settings > apps > Terminal Emulator > Force Stop .. After you have force stopped the app, wipe the data and cache then close app info settings, Try to open the app again and see if it closes normally

Comment: I saw another answer today and here's my update. I never did need a terminal again. I leave this to the next person who encounters my problem to try Firelord's suggestion and report. I have since moved to an LG G6 tethered to a Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

There are this ways :
1 - CTRL + D ( Volume Down + D )
2 - Tapping The "X" Button
3 - Typing The "exit" Command

Answer (score 0):

Simply tap on 3 dots and first close all Windows. When you close the last 1 window, you will be out of simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Close all windows of the terminal emulator and it'll automatically quit the app and close the notifications.

Answer (score -1):

There should be an "X" at the top of your screen. Just tap it.

Comment: It just re opens.